# Nav links don't active when adding scroll in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, scroll

First of all I need to say I'm quite new with html/css and know very few of js and jquery.

Now my problem. I'm finishing a website with Bootstrap, it has diferent containers working with scroll down. I looked for a scroll js code and it works good, but the problem is that nav links don't get active anymore. I've tried with diferent scroll scripts and solutions, but with my actual knowledge I can't figure out how to solve it. Again, the script works fine apart from not getting nav links active, and without it the web works good also.

This is my nav html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span><i class="icon-reorder"></i></span>
      </button>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active">
          <a href="#tebamar" title="tebamar" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-home icon-white"></i> Tebamar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="#">
          <a href="#quien" title="quien" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-group icon-white"></i> Nosotros</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#que" title="que" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-th icon-white"></i> Qué hacemos</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#donde" title="donde" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-map-marker icon-white"></i> Dónde</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#como" title="como" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-briefcase icon-white"></i> Cómo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contacto" title="contacto" class="scroll-page"><i class="icon-envelope-alt icon-white"></i> Contacto</a>
          </li>
        </ul></div></div></div></div>
```

and this the script I'm using:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
// Smooth animation when page scrolls
$("a.scroll-page").scrollToSection()

/* Initialise Carausel */
$('.carousel').carousel();

/* Initialise Tooltip */
$('[rel="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 

 });


jQuery.fn.scrollToSection = function(settings) {

settings = jQuery.extend({
    speed : 1000
}, settings);   

return this.each(function(){
    var caller = this
    $(caller).click(function (event) {  
        event.preventDefault()
        var locationHref = window.location.href
        var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

        var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
        if(elementClick == "#home"){
            destination = 0;
        }
        $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop:  destination}, settings.speed, function() {
            window.location.hash = elementClick;
        });
        return false;
    })
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do here, but to make the nav links active you can use something like this ( http://jsfiddle.net/wcRJQ/4/ ) :

```
$(".nav li").each(function()
{
    $(this).click(function(e) 
    {
        $(".nav .active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried but not working.. I'm sure all the code is quite messy right now, but this is the web http://www.tebamar.com/ the problem is the scroll works but when I add it the nav links doesn't get active

Comment: The code I mentioned should be added inside `$(document).ready(function()` . Did you check that jsfiddle I posted?

Comment: I did, you can check it in the html of www.tebamar.com but they don't become active